# Как в CIL работает инструкция switch

Tags: c#, cil, opcode

Никак не могу понять как инструкция [`switch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch?view=net-6.0) работает. Написал вот такой вот код (RELEASE):

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
switch(a)
{
    case 1:  Console.WriteLine(); break;
    case 2:  Console.WriteLine(); break;
    case 3:  Console.WriteLine(); break;
    case 15: Console.WriteLine(); break;
    default: Console.WriteLine(); break;
}
```

В IL я получил не совсем то, что ожидал (некоторые инструкции которые шли выше я не стал добавлять т.к там просто добавление/извлечение значений стека). Почему в `switch` передаются только 3 адреса? Почему необходимо добавлять дополнительные инструкции с `beq.s`? Разве не легче всё адреса инструкций засунуть в один `switch`, а для `default` оставить как есть (`br.s`)?

```
//Почему тут только 3 адреса передается в switch?
IL_000e: switch (IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032)

//Зачем этот блок нужен если можно передать IL_001f в switch... и т.д для каждого нового case
IL_001f: ldloc.0
IL_0020: ldc.i4.s 15
IL_0022: beq.s IL_0038

IL_0024: br.s IL_003e

IL_0026: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_002b: ret

IL_002c: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_0031: ret

IL_0032: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_0037: ret

IL_0038: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_003d: ret

IL_003e: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine()
IL_0043: ret
```

Comment: Так отработал компилятор, это с оптимизацией кода или без? Если без, то вообще нет смысла здесь что-либо обсуждать.

Comment: @aepot, Я это делал в Release, сайт sharplab.io

Comment: есть подозрение, что 1,2,3 типа по порядку идут, а 15 - отдельное число.

Comment: @aepot ивправду. Изменил 15 на 4 и в switch добавился еще один адрес

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще, чем казалось. Из документации по [`switch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch?view=net-6.0):

> Инструкция `switch` выводит значение из стека и сравнивает его, как беззнаковое целое, с N. Если значение меньше N, выполнение передается в конечный индекс, где цели пронумерованы от 0 (например, значение 0 принимает первую цель, значение 1 принимает вторую цель и так далее).

Если бы IL сгенерировал следующий код: `switch(IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032, IL_0038)`, то инструкция по адресу `IL_0038` выполнилась для числа 4, а не для 15. Таким образом, чтобы дойти до 15 необходимо будет сгенерировать такой код:

`switch(IL_0026, IL_002c, IL_0032, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_003e, IL_0038)`.

При таком коде, все числа [4;14] захватывались этим (C#) `switch` исполняя код начиная с `IL_003e` (блок `default`). В этом нет смысла, поэтому создается отдельный блок для числа, который идет не по числовому порядку в свиче (если скомпилить обратно из IL в C#, то получим обычный `if-else` отдельный от `switch`):

```
IL_001f: ldloc.0
IL_0020: ldc.i4.s 15
IL_0022: beq.s IL_0038
```

Ситуация прояснилась благодаря вот [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769051/17025310) ответу: